# Get an error using std::upper_bound on an Eigen library vector

Tags: c++, eigen, stl-algorithm

I am trying to use std::upper_bound with a vector defined by the Eigen libraries. I get some errors on visual studio 2017

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <algorithm>  

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    VectorXd myVector= VectorXd::LinSpaced(20, -1.5, 6.4);

    double trashold= strtod(argv[1], NULL);

    double firstGreaterValue= std::upper_bound(myVector(0), 
    myVector(myVector.size()-1),trashold);
}
```

I expect the program to return the position of the first element that is greater than my input (that in this case is 1.1).

I get these errors on compiling

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2794   'difference_type': is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of 'std::iterator_traits<_FwdIt>'   errorExample    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\algorithm   2347    
Error   C2938   '_Iter_diff_t<double>' : Failed to specialize alias template    errorExample    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\algorithm   2347    
Error   C2672   'std::distance': no matching overloaded function found  errorExample    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\algorithm   2347    
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type std::distance(_InIt,_InIt)' errorExample    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\algorithm   2347    
Error   C2794   'difference_type': is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of 'std::iterator_traits<_FwdIt>'   errorExample    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\algorithm   2351    
Error   C2938   '_Iter_diff_t<double>' : Failed to specialize alias template    errorExample    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\algorithm   2351    
Error   C2672   'std::advance': no matching overloaded function found   errorExample    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\algorithm   2353    
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'void std::advance(_InIt &,_Diff)'   errorExample    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\algorithm   2353    
Error   C2100   illegal indirection errorExample    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\algorithm   2355
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until Version 3.4, `Eigen::VectorXd` is not compatible with STL algorithms since it does not provide iterators to access its elements.

Since Version 3.4, [`Eigen`'s dense matrices and arrays provide STL compatible iterators](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSTL.html), then you can use `begin()`/`end()` method to get the iterator:

```
auto firstGreaterValueIter = std::upper_bound(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), trashold);
```

Also don't forget `std::upper_bound` returns an iterator, so you must dereference to get the value:

```
if (firstGreaterValueIter != myVector.end()) {
    double firstGreaterValue = *firstGreaterValueIter;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Prior to 3.4, you can still pass `vec.data()`, and `vec.data()+vec.size()` as a begin/end pair to STL algorithms.